# Test coverage using jest-junit fails in a create-react-app project

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

In a create-react-app/react-scripts@2.1.1 project, I'm trying to generate a coverage report using [jest-junit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-junit). Unfortunately, it fails with the following:

```
$ yarn run test --coverage
      Failed to write coverage reports:
      ERROR: Error: Invalid report format [jest-junit]
      STACK: Error: Invalid report format [jest-junit]
  at Object.module.exports.create (D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\istanbul-api\lib\input-error.js:6:15)
  at Reporter.add (D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\istanbul-api\lib\reporter.js:51:30)
  at D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\istanbul-api\lib\reporter.js:62:18
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Reporter.addAll (D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\istanbul-api\lib\reporter.js:61:14)
  at D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\jest-cli\build\reporters\coverage_reporter.js:180:18
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at step (D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\jest-cli\build\reporters\coverage_reporter.js:75:30)
  at D:\Users\username\Documents\Project\node_modules\jest-cli\build\reporters\coverage_reporter.js:86:15
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I encounter no errors if I run `yarn run test`. The following configuration block was added to the project's `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts",
      "!src/**/__stories__/",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "jest-junit"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Has anyone successfully configured jest-junit in a create-react-app@2 project?

Comment: Your configuration doesn't seem to match what's shown on the jest-junit page, why have you diverged from that?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for the quick comment. I wasn't paying close enough attention... my mistake was dropping jest-junit into coverageReporters (as opposed to reporters).

Unfortunately, create-react-app@2 does not appear to support a custom reporters configuration in package.json. Interestingly, the following command works:

```
$ yarn run test --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit
```

I'm used to most of create-react-app's configs overriding any explicitly defined options. However, it appears an exception (or loophole?) exists for `yarn run test`. With the above, I get the desired junit.xml file.

Comment: @twinlakes What do you mean by duplicate? In the end, I didn't add anything to `package.json`. I simply added the `--reporters` arguments to the test command.

Comment: It is because jest will produce two types of reports: **default** and **jest-junit**